# Adjusting left/right margins of a wrapfig

Tags: spacing, floats, wrapfigure

Is there a (simple) way to adjust the white space to the left or right of a `wrapfigure`? I'd like to reduce the whitespace on the left side of a right-floated figure.

Adding `\hspace` moves the figure to the left, it doesn't move the caption:

```
\begin{wrapfigure}{r}[.25in]{.98in}
\vspace{-20pt}
\hspace{-.25in}
   \centering
        \includegraphics[width=.98in]{figure.pdf}
   \caption{Caption}
    \label{fig:looping}
 \vspace{-6pt}
 \end{wrapfigure}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please complete your code snippet into a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The horizontal gap between the contents of the `wrapfig` environment and the surrounding paragraph text is `\columnsep` (from the [`wrapfig`](http://ctan.org/pkg/wrapfig) [documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/wrapfig/wrapfig-doc.pdf), section **2 Sizing and optional overhang**, p 3):

> LaTeX will wrap surrounding text around the ﬁgure, leaving a gap of `\intextsep` at
>   the top and bottom, and `\columsep` at the side, by producing a series of shortened text
>   lines beside the ﬁgure. The indentation (shortening) of the text is the ﬁgure width plus
>   `\columnsep` minus overhang (if any; see below).

Here's an example that shows the difference when setting `\columnsep` to `0pt`, and leaving it as-is:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{wrapfig,graphicx,lipsum}% http://ctan.org/pkg/{wrapfig,graphicx,lipsum}
\begin{document}
\begingroup
\setlength{\columnsep}{0pt}%
\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{.98in}
  \centering\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
  \caption{Caption}\label{fig:looping1}
\end{wrapfigure}
\lipsum[1]
\endgroup

\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{.98in}
  \centering\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
  \caption{Caption}\label{fig:looping2}
\end{wrapfigure}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

Adjust this to your liking. Use scoping (`\begingroup`...`\endgroup`, or similar) to localize any changes.

Note that you can therefore also use `\intextsep` as your vertical adjustment, rather than fixed values.

Comment: Putting my wrapfigure inside the group (even without the `setlength` command) removes the margin entirely and the text just covers the image.

Comment: @mangledorf: Don't leave a space between the `wrapfigure` environment and the subsequent paragraph. Check that you have the latest version of [`wrapfig`](http://ctan.org/pkg/wrapfig (3.6 according to CTAN). Also, it may be that your image has a faulty bounding box. It's not possible to guess what could cause that from what you mention.

Comment: @mangledorf, solution was to make sure my wrapped paragraph of text was inside the group and there was a blank line before `\endgroup`, See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/82647/strange-wrapfig-behavior#comment177024_82649

Comment: @mangledorf: Ahhh, a blank line signifies a paragraph break in (La)TeX, which `\lipsum` does inherently (unless you `\usepackge[nopar]{lipsum}`).