# usage of \lipsum[] leads to fake examples

Tags: errors, wrapfigure, wrap, lipsum, blindtext

This is more a comment than a question. I've tried several hours to wrap text around a picture using the `wrapfig` package.

Among others, I have relied on

[Adjusting left/right margins of a wrapfig](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/106144/adjusting-left-right-margins-of-a-wrapfig)

and

[Too much space around wrap figure](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/111393/too-much-space-around-wrap-figure)

as that is exactly what I am looking for. I could not get it working for one reason - I was using `\blindtext[]` instead of `\lipsum[]`. Interestingly, those examples not running with `lipsum` do not work with "real" input, neither. Have a look at my example:

```
    \documentclass[10pt,a5paper]{article}
    \usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
    \usepackage{wrapfig}
    \setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

    \usepackage{lipsum}
    \usepackage{blindtext}
    \begin{document}
    %########################## works with both lipsum and blindtext AND real text.
    \lipsum[1]
    %\blindtext[1]
    \begin{wrapfigure}[9]{r}{0.5\textwidth}
        \centering
            \vspace{-12pt}
        \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{cow.jpg}
    \end{wrapfigure}
    %\lipsum[1]
    \blindtext[1]
    %########################## works only on lipsum
    \newpage
    \lipsum[1]
    %\blindtext[1]
    \begingroup
        \setlength{\columnsep}{8pt}%    
        \setlength{\intextsep}{0pt}%
        \begin{wrapfigure}[9]{r}{0.5\textwidth}
            \centering
    %       \vspace{-12pt}
            \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{cow.jpg}
    %       \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{cow.jpg}
    %       \vspace{+12pt}
        \end{wrapfigure}
    %\lipsum[1]
    \blindtext[1]
    \endgroup
    \end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`\lipsum` ends the paragraph with `\par` you need the * form to avoid adding `\par` but the main reason the second example was overprinting is the somewhat brave use of wrapfig inside a local group, especially as you ended the group with blindtext not followed by a paragraph so you lost the parshape setting before the paragraph was set.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a5paper]{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
%########################## works with both lipsum and blindtext AND real text.
\lipsum[1]
%\blindtext[1]
\begin{wrapfigure}[9]{r}{0.5\textwidth}
    \centering
        \vspace{-12pt}
    \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{cow.jpg}
\end{wrapfigure}
%\lipsum[1]
\blindtext[1]
%########################## works only on lipsum
\newpage
\lipsum*[1]
%\blindtext[1]
\begingroup
    \setlength{\columnsep}{8pt}%    
    \setlength{\intextsep}{0pt}%
    \begin{wrapfigure}[9]{r}{0.5\textwidth}
        \centering
%       \vspace{-12pt}
        \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{cow.jpg}
%       \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{cow.jpg}
%       \vspace{+12pt}
    \end{wrapfigure}
%\lipsum[1]
\blindtext[1]\par
\endgroup
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you @DavidC for answering. `\par` after `\lipsum[]` or some text solves the issue.    
I did not feel good about using `wrapfigure`. It was, however, the only way I could have my images inline with some text after a gap.  
Still, the examples mentioned above do not address the problem.    
This one [http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/82647/strange-wrapfig-behavior#comment177024_82649] is a more specific in that matter.

Comment: @lactea nothing wrong with using wrapfig but using it surrounded by `\begingroup` `\endgroup` makes it _very_ fragile and you need to make sure if you do that that (a) you end the paragraph before `\endgroup` and (b) that you have enough text to wrap the figure within the group, but far simpler and safer is _not_ to surround wrapfig by the group.

Comment: I have tried that, too. I could not manage to _reliably_ have the top border of the image to be inline with the upper margin of the text field and have the `\columsep` at a given value. The document I am working on has always enough text to wrap around, so that is no concern.